# Point to Line Calculations

Tags: java, php, spherical-geometry

We are looking to take a point and compare it against the nearest point to an adjacent line.  All values are in lat/long.

We tried using some of the concept found on the board but found it did not work if the points share a same lat or long as it ends up multiplying by zero when subtracting the differences

Does anyone have working Java or PHP scripts they can share?
  Here is the code version 1 we have been working with

```
<?php

function IntersectionDAN ($startLat, $startLon, $endLat, $endLon, $pointlato, $pointlono)
{
    //Find if points are in the same plane
    if ($pointlato == $endLat) {
        return Intersectingdistance ($pointlato,$pointlono,$endlat,$endLon );
    }else
    if ($pointlono == $endlat) {
        return Intersectingdistance ($pointlato,$pointlono,$endlat,$endLon );
    }else
    if ($pointlato == $startLat) {
        return Intersectingdistance ($pointlato,$pointlono,$startLat,$startLon);
    }else
    if ($pointlono == $startLon) {
        return Intersectingdistance ($pointlato,$pointlono,$startLat,$startLon);
    }

    $startLat = ($startLat);
    $startLon = ($startLon);
    $endLat = ($endLat);
    $endLon = ($endLon);
    $pointlat = ($pointlato);
    $pointlon = ($pointlono);
    $Xline1 = $endLon - $startLon;
    $Yline2 = $endLat - $startLat;
    $ShortestLength =(($Xline1 *($pointlon - $startLon)) + ($Yline2 * ($pointlat - $startLat))) / (($Xline1 * $Xline1) + ($Yline2 *$Yline2));
    $Xcrosssection1lon = ($startLon + $Xline1) * $ShortestLength;
    $Ycrosssection1lat = ($endLat + $Yline2 )* $ShortestLength;
    if (($Ycrosssection1lat < $endLat && $Ycrosssection1lat > $endLon) && ($Xcrosssection1lon < $endLon && $Xcrosssection1lon > $startLon)) {
        return array(
            "lat" => $Ycrosssection1lat,
            "lon" => $Xcrosssection1lon
        );
    }else {
        echo "nothing";
    }

    var_dump($ShortestLength);
    var_dump($Ycrosssection1lat);
    var_dump($Xcrosssection1lon);

    return Intersectingdistance($pointlato, $pointlono, $Ycrosssection1lat, $Xcrosssection1lon);
}
function Intersectingdistance($pointlat,$pointlon,$Ycrosssection1lat,$Xcrosssection1lon)
{
$R = 6378.137; // Radius of earth in KM
    $pi = pi(); // It's delicious and cut precisely
    $pointlat = ($pointlat);
    $pointlon = ($pointlon);
    $Ycrosssection1lat = ($Ycrosssection1lat);
    $Xcrosssection1lon = ($Xcrosssection1lon);
    $dLat = ($pointlat - $Ycrosssection1lat);
    $dLon = ($pointlon - $Xcrosssection1lon);
    $a = sin(deg2rad($pointlat)) * sin(deg2rad($Ycrosssection1lat)) + cos(deg2rad($pointlat)) * cos(deg2rad($Ycrosssection1lat)) *sin(deg2rad($dLon));
    //$c = 2 * atan2(sqrt($a), sqrt(1 - $a));
    //$d = $R * $c;
    $a = rad2deg($a);
    $d = acos($a);
    $miles = $d * 60 * 1.1515;


    $Distance = ($miles); // feet
    var_dump($Distance);

}
$IntersectionDAN = IntersectionDAN(40.124423,-74.326886, 40.124561,-74.327066,40.124561,-74.326886);
```

In addion we have been working on a much more complex version and are completely stuck and getting the incorrect results back.

```
public function intersection($line1Lat, $line1Lon, $line1bear, $line2Lat, $line2Lon, $line2bear, &$line3Lat, &$line3Lon)
{
 $pi = pi();
    $line1Lat = $line1Lat * $pi / 180;
    $line1Lon = $line1Lon * $pi / 180;
    $line1bear = $line1bear * $pi / 180;
    $line2Lat = $line2Lat * $pi / 180;
    $line2Lon = $line2Lon * $pi / 180;
    $line2bear = $line2bear * $pi / 180;
    $dst12=2*asin(sqrt((sin(($line1Lat-$line2Lat)/2))*(sin(($line1Lat-$line2Lat)/2)) +cos($line1Lat)*cos($line2Lat)*(sin(($line1Lon-$line2Lon)/2))*(sin(($line1Lon-$line2Lon)/2))));
    if (sin($line2Lon-$line1Lon)<0)
    {
       $crs12=acos((sin($line2Lat)-sin($line1Lat)*cos($dst12))/(sin($dst12)*cos($line1Lat)));
       $crs21=2.*$pi-acos((sin($line1Lat)-sin($line2Lat)*cos($dst12))/(sin($dst12)*cos($line2Lat)));
    }
    else
    {
       $crs12=2.*$pi-acos((sin($line2Lat)-sin($line1Lat)*cos($dst12))/(sin($dst12)*cos($line1Lat)));
       $crs21=acos((sin($line1Lat)-sin($line2Lat)*cos($dst12))/(sin($dst12)*cos($line2Lat)));
    }

    $ang1=(crs13-$crs12+$pi)%(2.*$pi)-$pi;
    $ang2=($crs21-crs23+$pi)%(2.*$pi)-$pi;

    if (sin($ang1)==0 && sin($ang2)==0)
    {
        echo "infinity of intersections";
    }
    elseif (sin($ang1)*sin($ang2)<0)
    {
        echo "intersection ambiguous";
    }
    else
    {
       $ang1=abs($ang1);
       $ang2=abs($ang2);
       $ang3=acos(-cos($ang1)*cos($ang2)+sin($ang1)*sin($ang2)*cos($dst12));
       $dst13=atan2(sin($dst12)*sin($ang1)*sin($ang2),cos($ang2)+cos($ang1)*cos(ang3));
       $line3Lat=asin(sin($line1Lat)*cos($dst13)+cos($line1Lat)*sin($dst13)*cos(crs13));
       $dlon=atan2(sin(crs13)*sin($dst13)*cos($line1Lat),cos($dst13)-sin($line1Lat)*sin(lat3));
       $line3Lon=($line1Lon-$dlon+$pi)%(2*$pi)-$pi;
    }
}

public function bearing($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2)
{
    echo " Bearing Start ";
    $pi = pi();
    $lat1 = $lat1 * $pi / 180;
    $lon1 = $lon1 * $pi / 180;
    $lat2 = $lat2 * $pi / 180;
    $lon2 = $lon2 * $pi / 180;
    $dLon = ($lon2 - $lon1);
    $y = sin($dLon) * cos($lat2);
    var_dump($y);
    $x = cos($lat1)*sin($lat2)-sin($lat1)*cos($lat2)*cos($dLon);
    var_dump($x);
    echo " Bearing Stop ";
    return (atan2($y, $x) + (2*$pi))%(2*$pi) * 180 / $pi;
}

public function destination($lat, $lon, $bearing, $distance, &$outputLat, &$outputLon)
{
    $R = 6378.137; //km
    $pi = pi();
    $distance = $distance / 3.2808399 / 1000; //input feet to km
    $outputLat = asin(sin($lat * $pi / 180)*cos($distance/$R) + cos($lat * $pi / 180)*sin($distance/$R)*cos($bearing * $pi / 180)) * 180 / $pi;
    $outputLon = ($lon * $pi / 180 + atan2(sin($bearing * $pi / 180)*sin($distance/$R)*cos($lat * $pi / 180), cos($distance/$R)-sin($lat * $pi / 180)*sin($outputLat * $pi / 180))) * 180 / $pi;
}

public function crossProduct(&$v1, &$v2, &$vR)
{
    $vR[0] = (($v1[1] * $v2[2]) - ($v1[2] * $v2[1]));
    $vR[1] = -(($v1[0] * $v2[2]) - ($v1[2] * $v2[0]));
    $vR[2] = (($v1[0] * $v2[1]) - ($v1[1] * $v2[0]));
}

public function normalize(&$v1, &$vR)
{
    $fMag = sqrt((pow($v1[0], 2)) +
        (pow($v1[1], 2)) +
        (pow($v1[2], 2))
    );

    $vR[0] = $v1[0] / $fMag;
    $vR[1] = $v1[1] / $fMag;
    $vR[2] = $v1[2] / $fMag;

}

public function magnitude(&$vR)
{
    $fMag = sqrt((pow($vR[0], 2)) +
        (pow($vR[1], 2)) +
        (pow($vR[2], 2))
    );
    return $fMag;
}

/**
 * Determine distance between point and line in feet
 *
 * @param $xpoint1
 * @param $ypoint1
 * @param $xline2
 * @param $yline2
 * @param $xline3
 * @param $yline3
 * @return float
 */

public function pointToLineDistance($pointLat, $pointLon, $line1Lat, $line1Lon, $line2Lat, $line2Lon)
{

    if ($line1Lat < $line2Lat)
    {
        $temp1 = $line1Lat;
        $temp2 = $line1Lon;
        $line1Lat = $line2Lat;
        $line1Lon = $line2Lon;
        $line2Lat = $temp1;
        $line2Lon = $temp2;
    }
    $lineBear = $this->bearing($line2Lat, $line2Lon, $line1Lat, $line1Lon);
    echo "lineBear ";
    var_dump($lineBear);
    if ($lineBear > 180)
    {
        $temp1 = $line1Lat;
        $temp2 = $line1Lon;
        $line1Lat = $line2Lat;
        $line1Lon = $line2Lon;
        $line2Lat = $temp1;
        $line2Lon = $temp2;
    }
    echo "line1Lat ";
    var_dump($line1Lat);
    echo "line1Lon ";
    var_dump($line1Lon);
    echo "line2Lat ";
    var_dump($line2Lat);
    echo "line2Lon ";
    var_dump($line2Lon);
    $v1bear = $this->bearing($pointLat, $pointLon, $line1Lat, $line1Lon);
    echo "v1bear ";
    var_dump($v1bear);
    $v2bear = $this->bearing($pointLat, $pointLon, $line2Lat, $line2Lon);
    echo "v2bear ";
    var_dump($v2bear);
    $v1dist = $this->pointToPointDistance($pointLat, $pointLon, $line1Lat, $line1Lon);
    echo "v1dist ";
    var_dump($v1dist);
    $v2dist = $this->pointToPointDistance($pointLat, $pointLon, $line2Lat, $line2Lon);
    echo "v2dist ";
    var_dump($v2dist);
    $v1[0] = sin((180-($v1bear-$lineBear)+360)%360 * $pi / 180) * $v1dist;
    $v1[1] = cos((180-($v1bear-$lineBear)+360)%360 * $pi / 180) * $v1dist;
    $v1[2] = 0;
    echo "v1";
    var_dump($v1);
    $v2[0] = sin(($v2bear+$lineBear+360)%360 * $pi / 180) * $v2dist;
    $v2[1] = cos(($v2bear+$lineBear+360)%360 * $pi / 180) * $v2dist;
    $v2[2] = 0;
    echo "v2";
    var_dump($v2);
    $vR = null;
    $this->crossProduct($v1, $v2, $vR);
    echo "vR";
    var_dump($vR);
    $mag = $this->magnitude($vR);
    echo "vR mag";
    var_dump($mag);
    $mag2 = $this->pointToPointDistance($line1Lat, $line1Lon, $line2Lat, $line2Lon);
    echo "line mag";
    var_dump($mag2);
    $d = $mag / $mag2;
    echo "result";
    var_dump($d);
    //$R = 6378.137;
    //$d = $d * 1000 * 3.2808;
    return $d;
```

Our goal is to have an accurate Point to Line Segment  Calculation so point C can be compared against Line AB

Sorry for the confusion here and hope you can help
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. Could you point to the concepts you relied on and how you interpreted them? Use the **[edit]** button.

Comment: I'm confused by your [tag:spherical-geometry] tag, because there is no mention of spherical geometry in your Question body, so when you edit your Question can you explain its significance, please?

Comment: @PolyGeo: "... nearest point to an adjacent line. All values are in lat/long." => spherical geom.

Comment: @martinf I'd still like to see something more explicit as part of the Question; it might not make real world sense but lat/long can be labelled on axes of rectangular grid, and distances calculated in decimal degrees.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend to rely on **GeographicLib** implemented by Charles Karney which uses Gnomonic projection for point to line projections in WGS-84 (http://geographiclib.sourceforge.net/). This solution is discussed and proven to be highly accurate in *Charles Karney, Algorithms for geodesics* (http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00190-012-0578-z).

A limitation of GeographicLib is that it only implements Gnomonic projection and leaves open concrete implementation of point to line projection.

**Barefoot library** implements that last mile in Java and is based on GeographicLib's Gnomonic projection (https://github.com/bmwcarit/barefoot):

It provides an interface that is similar to what can be found in PostGIS, where PostGIS does not work for geodesics, i.e. lines on the earth surface (see note below). It determines a point P on line semgent A to B that is closest to some point C. In PostGIS, this can be achieved (but only for cartesian coordinate system) with ST_LineLocatePoint (http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.2/ST_LineLocatePoint.html) that returns an offset/fraction between 0 and 1 defining the position of P between A and B. Coordinates of P can then be determined using ST_LineInterpolatePoint (http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.2/ST_LineInterpolatePoint.html). Barefoot library provides that for geodesic lines (lines on earth surface) as shown in the following code example (https://github.com/bmwcarit/barefoot#spatial-operations):

```
SpatialOperator spatial = new Geography();

Point reykjavik = new Point(-21.933333, 64.15);
Point moskva = new Point(37.616667, 55.75);
Point berlin = new Point(13.408056, 52.518611);

double f = spatial.intercept(reykjavik, moskva, berlin);
Point interception = spatial.interpolate(reykjavik, moskva, f);
```

**Note:** As of PostGIS 2.2 the forementioned PostGIS operations are not compatible with PostGIS Geography data structures and, hence, do not work for geodesic lines, i.e. lines on the earth surface.

[image: https://github.com/bmwcarit/barefoot/blob/master/doc-files/com/bmwcarit/barefoot/spatial/intercept-satellite.png]

[image: https://github.com/bmwcarit/barefoot/raw/master/doc-files/com/bmwcarit/barefoot/spatial/radius-satellite.png]